# Why is my navbar alignment out for both horizontal and vertical media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to create a navbar in pure html/css that at less than 600px width is horizontal with a horizontal set of links inline (no bullet points). At more than 600px width, I want a vertical navbar with a vertical list.

However, my horizontal version keeps giving me a vertically stacked set with bullet points and my vertical version has the word 'links' inline with 'paragraph' when I want it underneath.

I'm at a fault to see what I'm doing wrong. I tried scrubbing it out and starting again which worked until I put in my media query and it all went wrong again. Any help appreciated.

```
<header>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <h1>HTML Basics</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Documents</li>
      <li>Headings</li>
      <li>Paragraph</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Images</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

```
#navbar{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
  float: top;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px){
  #navbar{
  background: red;
  width: 22%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


li{
  list-style: none;
 padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10%;
  float: left;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
  li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
}

li:hover{
  color:#911f32;
  font-size: 18px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly brace in your first Media Query. Try this:

```
#navbar {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
  float: top;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  #navbar {
    background: red;
    width: 22%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  } // <-- NOTE! This curly brace was missing...
}


li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10%;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

li:hover{
  color: #911f32;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some errors in there:

- You used `min-width` both times instead of min/max
- For the horizontal version you need to allow full width (100%)
- You forgot a closing curly brace
- There is no `float: top;` (but that has no effect anyway)

```css
#navbar {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  #navbar {
    background: red;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10%;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:600px) {
  #navbar {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

li:hover {
  color: #911f32;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <h1>HTML Basics</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Documents</li>
      <li>Headings</li>
      <li>Paragraph</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Images</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add style for your list-item element (600px and down).
2. Comment unnecessary style (600px and up).

Look at CSS code below.

```css
#navbar{
  /* ... */
}

/* === Add this code */
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px){
  #navbar {
   /* ... */
  }

  /* ===
  You don't need 
  "display: inline-block" and 
  "float: left" 
  */
  li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    margin-left: 10%;
    /* float: left; */
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  /*...*/
```